# Saving 2D Arrays (high frequency) - structure needed

Tags: .net, database, arrays, io, rrd

I´m searching for a solution to store 2D (int) Arrays to local disc - doesn´t sound very hard, but the frequency and the size of the arrays keep bothering me.

The array size is [1400][400] and at peak times, we´re getting every 50ms an array.

How much do we need to store? At least, every array of the last hour - after that, just ony array per minute for 7 days - after that, only an array for every hour for 2 years.

First I thought about an RRD Tool with the NHawk Interface, but it can´t store whole Arrays.
Second Thought: Database (like MS SQL), but I think its to slow for this or you need a very powerful machine.

Is there maybe another option for our problem?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know enough about it but this article seems to imply NHawk can store arrays of objects, granted its not going to be as good as having them as raw ints:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28763/C-Hooks-For-RRDtool

If you are having to do this manually and the above does not help could you not just store the array as an image (as the int could be easily transferred to a colour) then store it on the file system somewhere and put an entry into a database which points to the file system? I mean you could use a blob but you would eat space in the database. I dont know how intelligent you want your solution to be, as each array would be like 2mb in size, and if thats happening almost 20 times a second that 40mb a second your going to eat up. So you need scaleable storage, so you may want to look at using cloud storage or something and just dump your files there and just have a thin layer which wraps and records the entries but not the data...

Without more information on how good your soluition needs to be (i.e. quick hack or large maintainable system). its difficult to propose relevant solutions.